# Sending an email with attachments programmatically on Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent, email-attachments

I wish to implement a button that upon pressing it will open the default email client with an attachment file.

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355870/explicit-intent-for-android-default-email-client), but am getting an error message on the startActivity, saying it is expecting an activity param while I am giving it an intent.
I am using API 21 and Android Studio 1.1.0, so perhaps it has something to do with the comment in the answer provided in the link?

This is my fourth day as Android developer so sorry if I am missing something really basic.

Here is my code:

```
    public void sendFileToEmail(File f){

    String subject = "Lap times";
    ArrayList<Uri> attachments = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    attachments.add(Uri.fromFile(f));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachments);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.mail.compose.ComposeActivity");

    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: accept my answer if it is worked for you. So that you can avoid this question from  the un-answered question list in SOF

Answer (score 37, accepted):

***Official documentation with Kotlin snippets is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ComposeEmail***

I think your problem is that you are not using the correct file path.

The following works for me:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@example.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String pathToMyAttachedFile = "temp/attachement.xml";
File file = new File(root, pathToMyAttachedFile);
if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
    return;
}
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an Email provider"));
```

**EDIT:** Requesting access to storage just to share a file private to your app is probably not a good idea. Fortunately, after a little configuration, it's very easy to share a file from your app private storage. See this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing

If you share a file that is on external storage, you also need to give the user permission via a manifest file like below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: The file is a parameter to the function so I don't see how this could be the issue.

Comment: File is a parameter only, but you need to check whether it is available are not. And you need to give the read External Storage permission to read the files.

Comment: Happy to help @Jasmine !! Enjoy coding

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: I had to replace `getExternalStorageDirectory()` with `getExternalCacheDir()` [(see this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27286061/900394)

Answer (score 6):

For newer devices you will encounter FileUriExposedException. Here is how to avoid it in Kotlin.

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "this")
val authority = context.packageName + ".provider"
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authority, file)
val emailIntent = createEmailIntent(uri)
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."))

private fun createEmailIntent(attachmentUri: Uri): Intent {
    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    emailIntent.type = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/email"
    val to = arrayOf("some@email.com")
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachmentUri)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject")
    return emailIntent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this.It is working...

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                    emailIntent.setType("*/*");

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(listVideos.get(position).getVideoPath())));//path of video 
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Thanks