# Is there any way to avoid this screen while accessing "mailto:"?

Tags: android, cordova, mailto

I am trying to use mailto link in my app but when clicking that link, I am getting a screen saying

> "Webpage not available and some error", although email application
>   opens properly but I want to bypass that background error page.

Please note that I am using following code inside the button click:

```
window.open('mailto:alok1141@gmail.com?subject=Feedback: Competitive Aptitude');
```

Please suggest any way to avoid this background page.
[Image with background error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xbjy.jpg)

Comment: The best way to send an email is asking for a client, because you don't know what email client is using the customer

Comment: Thanks Buddy, You got the right idea but I guess there is not any attribute available to select the specific email client.
Can you suggest me any alternative.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I think that you need this code for send an email by android email system app (default): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355870/explicit-intent-for-android-default-email-client, hope to be helpful! look at **setClassName(...)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,
I found the solution. Actually when you run the application in phonegap app it will not open href="mailto: xyz@email.com" thats why I had to use window.open,

but once you will build the app even href="mailto: xyz@email.com" will work and best thing is it will directly open the app and no background error page will appear.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you need to use a link `<a href="mailto:...">` instead of a button or maybe use `window.location=...` in the `onClick` so that the browser can present the popup directly.

Now you tell the browser to open a window with the mailto url so only after the window has been opened it will check the url and present the popup.

Comment: mailto inside <a href=''> tag is not working, that is why I had to use javascript's window.open code.

Answer (score 0):

There's two kind of format `"mailto:"` or `"message/rfc822"` MIME type. You have to add it on `Intent` with `setType()` If no app supports both, then it will shows the default chooser.

Comment: I am using phonegap, I am not sure this code can be used there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the target to *_system*? It could be that your app is attempting to handle the link itself and failing. By setting the target to *_system*, you are asking the OS to open it for you.

```
window.open('mailto:alok1141@gmail.com?subject=Feedback: Competitive Aptitude', '_system');
```

You will also need the inappbrowser plugin. This plugin ensures that adding *_system* actually works. I believe on Android you may not need this, but you definitely will for iOS.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Comment: Thanks,
I found the solution. Actually when you run the application in phonegap app it will not open href="mailto: xyz@email.com" thats why I had to use window.open,

 but once you will build the app even href="mailto: xyz@email.com" will work and best thing is it will directly open the app and no background error page wil appear